# is it possible to insert a cloned sheet to a different workbook? APACHE POI

Tags: apache, apache-poi

i'm not sure if my question is a bit silly but once I clone a sheet from an existing workbook, how do I "IMPORT" it to another workbook? or is that the way is it supposed to work? API said that it would spit out a cloned sheet from an existing workbook but what can you do to that extracted sheet? how does it get included on a workbook?

i'm looking at the HSSFWorkbook API but I don't see any method that would let me use a sheet (cloned) and add it to a different workbook. or did I just missed a method on the API list.

Answer (score 0):

the clone method seems to only work within the workbook itself. it will clone it on the workbook where the sheet originated.